# Is it impossible to dump a database from a server?

Tags: android

when I upload db file to server using php and recover that file, the database date in android device explorer is updated. but the contents is not updated. I dont understand... 
time is updated but not contents... what's going on? using retrofit2 for upload/download, the result log is success, and the file size is right "4kb".  is there anyone? I'm so alone.... because when I ask a question, there is no one who answered to me....

ps : the file permissions are like this "-rw-rw----"
and here is my code to dump downloaded file to original file

```
 private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
        try {
            // todo change the file location/name according to your needs
            File futureStudioIconFile = new File(file.getPath());

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                    Log.d("TAG", "file download: " + fileSizeDownloaded + " of " + fileSize);
                }

                outputStream.flush();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here is response about download. please help me....

```
responseBodyCall = retrofitInterface.download("savelocation");
                responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        Log.d("Success", "success "+response.code());
                        Log.d("Success", "success "+response.message());
                        Log.d("Success", "downloaded");

                        boolean isSuccess = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());
                        if(isSuccess) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
                        Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
                    }
                });
```